# Unable to login using facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I am using Facebook login in my app. Previously it was worked fine, that app is also is in play store. But from fast few days i am unable to login with Facebook.
cureently am getting this error.
[image: Am getting the following error]
**We have using fallowing code in my app**

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.0.0'


    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("Email", "public_profile"));
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            getUserProfile(loginResult);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        }
    });
 private void getUserProfile(LoginResult currentAccessToken) {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            currentAccessToken.getAccessToken(), (object, response) -> {
                try {
                    firstName = object.getString(Constants.FACEBOOK.FIRST_NAME);
                    lastName = object.getString(Constants.FACEBOOK.LAST_NAME);
                    email = object.optString(Constants.FACEBOOK.EMAIL, "");
                    id = object.getString(Constants.FACEBOOK.ID);
                    imageUrl = String.format(getString(R.string.profile_pic_url), id);

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                        fbSigUp = true;
                        //facebook to getting email null
                        gettingEmail(null);
                    } else {
                        loginWS();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString(getString(R.string.field), getString(R.string.fbrequiedfields));
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

So can anybody help me to figure it out.

Comment: This may be due to facebook SDK issue or some problem with FB server. You can check with the FB support team regarding this.

Comment: They are not responding